# Questions about WordPress.org theme review

Tags: theme-development, wordpress.org, theme-review

I have created one theme. The theme [was denied today](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3777) for the following reasons:

> Theme Review:
>
> - Themes should be reviewed using `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php`
> - Themes should be reviewed using the test data from the Theme Checklists
>     (TC)

`wp-config.php` is the WordPress setting file. How do I alter my custom theme?

> - the theme registers some custom functionality in the function
>     `warmHome_setup()` however this function in not hooked so the functionality
>     is not available. Recommend hooking the theme to the `after_setup_theme`
>     hook.

The following is my themes `warmHome_setup()` function. How should I alter it?

```
function warmHome_setup() {

    // This theme styles the visual editor with editor-style.css to match the theme style.
    add_editor_style();

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // Make theme available for translation
    // Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory
    load_theme_textdomain( 'warm-home', TEMPLATEPATH . '/languages' );

    $locale = get_locale();
    $locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH . "/languages/$locale.php";
    if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) )
        require_once( $locale_file );

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'warm home' ),
    ) );

    // This theme allows users to set a custom background
    add_custom_background();
    }
```

Comment: Please note: these are questions you should be asking *in the Trac ticket*. The Theme Reviewers are there to *help* you answer such questions.

Comment: @Chip: I [created a Trac question](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/648/should-we-answer-questions-about-theme-reviews) to discuss whether we should answer these questions on WPSE. Could you please give your opinion too?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: done! Thanks for pointing it out to me; I don't usually spend much time on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> the wp-config.php is wordpress setting file. how to alter my custom theme?

you don't need to alter your theme, its simply telling you to turn debug to true within wp-config.php and review your theme, to see if it creating any warnings or errors.
put this line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php and play around with your site, see if you get any warnings or errors and correct them.

> the following is my themes warmHome_setup() function. how to alter it? many thanks.

simply add  `add_action('after_setup_theme','warmHome_setup');` to your functions.php file

For example:

```
function warmHome_setup() {
    // all your setup functionality goes here
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'warmHome_setup');
```

Comment: Glad i can help.

Comment: when i should add add_action() to my custommed function. thank you.

Comment: anywhere in your functions.php file is fine.

Comment: i means if i have custommed lots of functions. which one or all the functions that i should  add add_action()?

Comment: Functions are used in one of two ways in WordPress Themes: either the function is called directly in a template file, or else the function is *hooked in* via the Hooks API, either to filter some existing content, or else to add some content or functionality at a specific location/execution point. Which to use depends upon what you're doing with the function.

Comment: @Baiternet p.s. I hope you don't mind, I edited your answer a bit, to clarify how the `add_action()` call pairs with the `function warmHome_setup()` function declaration.