# questions of submit wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about submitting theme to WordPress.org](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16727/questions-about-submitting-theme-to-wordpress-org)

I have created one themes. which is still pending approval or denial. the  theme was denied today for the following reasons:

```
Theme Review:
 - Themes should be reviewed using "define('WP_DEBUG', true);" in wp-
 config.php
 - Themes should be reviewed using the test data from the Theme Checklists
     ...........
 (TC)
```

the wp-config.php is wordpress setting file. how to allter my custom theme. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This does not mean that `WP_DEBUG` has anything to do with your theme code. That means that your theme generates error/warning/notice messages when output of error messages is enabled (WP suppresses output of errors by default).

You will need to [enable `WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) on stack where you test your theme and fix all such messages.