# Theme Review: post thumbnail, header image, content width

Tags: theme-development, wordpress.org, theme-review

A followup to [my previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16727/questions-about-wordpress-org-theme-review) about my theme that was [rejected for the WordPress.org theme directory](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3777):

> - RECOMMENDED: No reference to the_post_thumbnail() was found in the theme. It is recommended that the theme implement this functionality instead of using custom fields for thumbnails.
> - RECOMMENDED: No reference to add_custom_image_header was found in the theme. It is recommended that the theme implement this functionality if using an image for the header.

How do I correct it? This is my function:

```
// thumbnail list 
function retImage($content){
     $pattern="/<img.*?src=[\'|\"](.*?(?:[\.gif|\.jpg]))[\'|\"].*?[\/]?>/";
     preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$match); 
     if(empty($match[0][0])){
                 echo "<img src=\"";
                 bloginfo('template_url');
                 echo "/images/thumbnail.png\" />";
     }else{
         echo  $match[0][0];
     }
}
```

I used  an image for the header by css, why do they say this:

> - RECOMMENDED: No reference to add_custom_image_header was found in the theme.

[image: Header image CSS rules]

> - Embedded videos overlap sidebar. Please set the content_width variable

In my the `functions.php` of my theme I did this:

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 992;
```

Why do they still give me that tip?

Comment: Is there some reason that you're asking these questions on WPSE, rather than *in the Trac ticket*, or via the theme-reviewers mail list?

Comment: @Chip Bennet: Yes, he’s getting upvotes here. :)

Comment: (That was my up-vote ;) ). Up-votes are nice and all, but they're not necessarily useful toward getting one's Theme approved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> RECOMMENDED: No reference to the_post_thumbnail() was found in the theme. It is recommended that the theme implement this functionality instead of using custom fields for thumbnails.

This is because you are not using `the_post_thumbnail()` in your theme, you are trying to get an image from the post content. This means there is no way for a user to explicitly set which image is shown wherever you are using `retImage()`. I would include the ability for `retImage()` to try use the thumbnail, something like:

```
// thumbnail list 
function retImage($content) {

    if( has_post_thumbnail() )
         return the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); 

    $pattern="/<img.*?src=[\'|\"](.*?(?:[\.gif|\.jpg]))[\'|\"].*?[\/]?>/";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$match); 
    if(empty($match[0][0])){
             echo "<img src=\"";
             bloginfo('template_url');
             echo "/images/thumbnail.png\" />";
    } else {

        echo  $match[0][0];
    }
}
```

You may also need to include `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )` in your `functions.php`

> RECOMMENDED: No reference to add_custom_image_header was found in the theme. It is recommended that the theme implement this functionality if using an image for the header.

If you theme has a header image, it is recommended to use the WordPress header image API, you can find out more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_image_header

This would enable the user to change the header image via the admin (Appearance -> Custom Header) or something alike.

> Embedded videos overlap sidebar. Please set the content_width variable
>   The `$content_width` should be a global variable:

```
global $content_width;
$content_width = 960;
```

Comment: if i want to do a fixed image to my theme's header.namely, not make the user can change the header. how do i do?

Comment: i am also find some themes form the wordpress.org whose using a header image by css.

Comment: do you know questions 3. why i get "Please set the content_width variable" tip?

Comment: Re the header: It's just a recommendation - if you don't want the ability for the user to change the header, don't do include it. Any other themes on the repo that don't let you change the image would also come up against this warning.

Comment: I added a note on the `$content_width`.

Comment: but i see that in the twenty theme's function.php it also define it as this if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 992;
 why?many thanks

Comment: @enjoylife: The `$content_width` should be the width of your main content area (where you display the blog text), not including the sidebars. I suspect the 992 pixels is the width of the whole theme? For Twenty Ten it's 640, for example.

Comment: Note also that 3 of the 4 things you ask about are only *recommendations*. Only `$content_width` is *required* to be set appropriately for your Theme.

Comment: you're right.960pixels is my theme's whole width.